# Pop-Up with ASP.Net Button Click that is not blocked with popup blocker

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I currently have an ASP.Net button click event that does a few things (including change session variables) prior to registering a new startup script  As is, when a user clicks the button, their pop-up blocker blocks the popup even though it was technically triggered by a user event; I imagine the browser doesn't see it that way.

```
protected void ContinueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (agreement.Checked)
    {
        string eid = Request.QueryString["eid"];
        Session["TestAgreement"] = "Agreed";
        openNewWindow("Exams/exam.aspx?id=" + courseCode, "height=760, width=1000, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, scrollbars=1");
    }          
}
private void openNewWindow(string url, string parameters)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Exam", String.Format("<script>window.open('" + url + "', '', '" + parameters + "');</script>"));
}
```

Comment: add an exception to the ad blocker for your website.

Comment: you can also replace the button with a link and set target="_blank". this will open a new window and send the request from the new window, avoiding the pop-up blocker.

Comment: @AnnArbor87 - I don't want to force all of my users to add an exception

Comment: @JasonMeckley I still need to perform some server side code.  I want to update a session variable, so I need to do this server side before the window is created.

Comment: nothing prevents you from executing server side code. understanding how the web & browser behave will allow you to make a more informed technical decision. what you want isn't a problem, but the implementation seems questionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AjaxControlToolkit's modal popup works nicely for this sort of thing.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

its still within the asp.net framework so you still get all your server side goodness, and you can always pop a usercontrol inside of it so that you can treat it as a separate "page"

just remember to keep your cclientidmode on your objects as static or predictable if you want to be able to hit them from your client side.

Comment: forgot to mention, it is also possible to spawn it from the server which makes it a bit niftier than a purely client popup like jquery

Comment: the full package is really nice. lots of cool toys. btw DevExpress has some nice asp.net popup stuff, but its a bit pricey tho.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with javascript.
Do not open a new Window, just set a div in front and change its content.

The easiest would be, to use Jquery Dialog:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have considered the Dialog box, but the pop-up contains plenty of server side code as well that I want separate from the rest of the page.